# issue in wordpress auto delete post and redirect to another 1

Tags: posts, admin, wp-admin, redirect, customization

i am getting strange issue on WordPress, 
my site is huge traffic and database.
one thing.. my WordPress is updated 4.4.2 all plugins updated.
now i get issue when i publish new post most of the posts deleted first time.
after publish i check view post it works fine and vie. 
and then after 1 minute post deleted and not showing in all posts section in admin, if i manual open link then it redirect to another post.
 i checked no redirection set to any of these post.
i used 301 redirect plugin if i need set redirect,
please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: no knows about this problem ?: - /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i get solution from senior developer and tested.. problem is too many revisions and auto draft that's why WordPress confuses to save new posts.. it works. i just install a plugin `WP-optimize` and click proceed it delete all posts which has status revision and auto draft.

regards,
ahsan